# Python: How to separate the function read file and display user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, tuples

I'm having a hard time separating the functions. I'm trying to have a read function where it reads the text file that I have (which is separated by a ',' in the text file). However, I currently have it under `display_university`. The display function should display the format like the category 'if' conditional on my code below. The `["UniversityName"]` and `["ContactName"]` are all headers from the text file.(It's like reading from a database a displaying the contents under that heading).

The text file is currently like this:

```
"UniversityName","ContactName"
"UCLA","John Kelly"
"UofFlorida","Mary Elizabeth"
"U of Memphis","Taylor Johnson"
"Harvard","Robert Fax"
```

So depending on what the user enters it would display the contents under that heading. Right now I have it as University and Contact. On the main file, I have the user have a choice to what they want to display.

My program right now is supposed to sort by University or Contact. So if I were to choose 1. (university), the output should list all of the university names in order:

```
University: Harvard
Name: Robert Fax

University: UCLA
Name: John Kelly

Name: UofFlorida
Name: Mary Elizabeth
....
```

I have the read function commented out at the moment and how I want to display. I just don't know how to separate the function because of my print statements. I've been getting weird loop errors. I feel like my placement is wrong.

Code:

```
import csv

def display_university(filename, category):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
           if line_count == 0:
                print(f'{", ".join(row)}')
                line_count += 1
        if category == "University":
            print(f'University: {row["UniversityName"]}'
                  f'\nName: {row["ContactName"]}')
        if category == "Contact":
            print(f'Contact: {row["ContactName"]}'
                  f'\nUniversity: {row["UniversityName"]}')
        line_count += 1
    print(f'\nProcessed {line_count} lines.')


def main():
    filename = "List.txt"

    # list_files = read_file(filename)
    try:
        print("1. University")
        print("2. Contact Name")
        choice = input()
        choice = int(choice)

        if choice == '1':
            # display_university(list_files, "University")
        elif choice == '2':
            # display_university(list_files, "Contact")

        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid option selected")

    except ValueError:
        print("Unexpected error.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @Mogambo I just added it on my explanation

Comment: is your for loop properly indented as the one you have pasted here is not

Comment: I speculatively indented your `main` function definition because as posted it was a syntax error. Please review.

Comment: @tripleee you beat me to it. I was about to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Having all the information on a single line in a CSV file is an odd and inconvenient design. Is there any way you could fix the wacky input file format instead, or as well?

Comment: I *guess* your question is "how can I read but not print". The simple answer to that is to have your function return the results it collected into a list or dict.

Comment: @tripleee How can I read and print using separate functions is what I'm trying to do. It just sounded so complicated inside my head I guess. I'm having trouble doing both.

Comment: Actually the sample input file does not look like what your code expects to read. Is the actual file multiple lines with two fields on each?

Comment: It reads as:
"UniversityName","ContactName" 
(newline)
"UCLA", "John Kelly"
(it's a new line everytime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *guessing* you are looking for something like this. Read the CSV into a `dict` where each key is a university name and the value is a list of contacts as strings.  Then have a separate function select what to print from that dict.

```
import csv
import logging

def read_university_contacts(filename):
    """
    Read CSV file into a dict and return it.
    """
    with open(filename, mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        university_contacts = dict()
        for line_count, row in enumerate(csv_reader, 1):
           if line_count == 1:
                # Not sure why you have this, skip header?
                #continue
                pass
           university = row["UniversityName"]
           contact = row["ContactName"]
           if university not in university_contacts:
               university_contacts[university] = [contact]
           else:
               university_contacts[university].append(contact)
    # Use logging for diagnostics
    logging.info(f'Processed {line_count} lines')
    # Return the structure we read
    return university_contacts    

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(module)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
    contacts = read_university_contacts("List.txt")

    while True:
        try:
            print("1. University")
            print("2. Contact Name")
            choice = input()
            choice = int(choice)
            break
        except ValueError:
            logging.warning("Unexpected error.")

    # Don't compare to string; you converted to int() above
    if choice == 1:
        print(list(contacts.keys()))
    elif choice == 2:
        print(list(contacts.values()))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid option selected")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: YES! sort of, but I think your indentation is off. I'm trying to run it on my IDE

Comment: Hmm? Maybe reload the page, I had to fix up indentation in one place but I did that immediately after posting so it's not visible as a separate edit.

Comment: the comments keeps messing it up, do you mind sending a repl link or something similar of it?

Comment: Sorry, indentation fixed here too now (one space too many crept in somehow). Also https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickShallowProperties

Comment: do you happen to know how to sort the row by the first letter of each university and name?

Comment: Of course, but that's a separate question. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting